# Disable past dates on dhtmlx Mini Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have implemented DHTMLX schedules to show events on my website. Scheduler on dashboard also have DHTMLX calendar which used to select week for dhtmlx scheduler.

here is an sample:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/05_calendar/05_plain_structure.html

Here is my code that I've written to generate DHTMLX calendar.

```
var calendar = scheduler.renderCalendar({
                    container:"cal_here",
                    date:scheduler._date,
                    navigation:true,
                    handler:function(nwdate,calendar){
                    var date = new Date(nwdate);
                    getdate=date.getFullYear()+ '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1)+ '-' +date.getDate();
                    scheduler.setCurrentView(date, scheduler._mode);
                    }
                });
```

I went through documentation but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Updated :

You can use the setSensitiveRange

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxcalendar:api_method_dhtmlxcalendar_setsensitive

Pass null as a second parameter

Comment: Thanks Tarek.. But this doesn't seem to be working. I need date limitation on calendar not on scheduler.

Comment: So you just want to completely hide the calendar ?

Comment: No I just want to disable past dates on Mini Calendar.

Comment: I tried that too. it says "calendar.setSensitiveRange is not a function";

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using the calendar or the scheduler because calendar are instantiated using : var myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject

Comment: Yes exactly. I tried it in that way too but the mini calendar that I'm using is co ordinate with scheduler. So this doesn't work with it. see the sample link I've given on question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46844/discussion-between-mahendra-and-tarek)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize Date for your html Calendar
Add this code in the form_load!

```
> scheduler.InitialDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01);
```

You might want to know more, visit the following site;

> http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/simple-event-calendar-asp-net.aspx